# How to have an array of all ids as a result of a mongodb projection?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, projection, mongodb-compass

I have the following query:

```
@Query(value = "{ '_id': { \$in : ?0 } }", fields = "{ 'ids': '\$_id', '_id': 0 }")
fun findExistingIds(ids: Set<ObjectId>): Mono<ExistingIds>
```

The `ExistingIds` is a class that contains a List of Strings:

```
data class ExistingIds(val ids: List<String>)
```

What I want to achieve is the above query to return a list of the existing ids, but instead it returns the ids separately and not all in one. (And thats the reason I get the following exception)

> Caused by: org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Query {...} returned non unique result.

I tested the query on Mongo Compass as well and this is the result
[image]

I also tried to have it as an array but again it creates separate arrays as
[image]

Any idea how I can solve this? Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: you can do this using `$aggregate` and `$push` [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LybNaQ71iyJ)

Comment: @1sina1 thanks for your answer, so that means instead of `@Query` I must use `@Aggregation`?

Comment: yeah you must use [@aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) but sorry idk about  `spring-boot`

Comment: No worries, thanks for the clarification, I will rewrite the query as an aggregation

Answer (score 0):

Based on @1sina1 answer I rewrote the `@Query` to `@Aggregation` as:

```
    //@Query(value = "{ '_id': { \$in : ?0 } }", fields = "{ 'ids': '\$_id', '_id': 0 }")
    @org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Aggregation(
        value = [
            "{ '\$match': { '_id': { '\$in' : ?0 } } }",
            "{ '\$project': { 'ids':'\$_id', '_id': 0 } }",
            "{ '\$group': { '_id': null, 'ids': { '\$push': '\$ids' } } }",
            "{ '\$project': { 'ids': 1, '_id': 0 } }"
        ]
    )
    fun findExistingIds(ids: Set<ObjectId>): Mono<ExistingIds>
```